# Delete last character in stdout buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffer, stdout, apache-nifi

In Python 3.7, I am trying to write a JSON array to stdout and I would like to remove the final comma in the array

```
sys.stdout.write("[")
[sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(x, separators=(',', ': ')) + ",") for x in list]
sys.stdout.write("\b]")  # I want to remove the final ',' from above.
```

I know `sys.stdout` is buffered, so what I'd like to do is remove the last character in that buffer before the flush. The only problem is I don't know how to properly access that buffer as well as ensure the final byte is not written.

I messed with the `\b` character however that does nothing, all that happens is the `\b` character becomes part of the output.

As a background, the stdout is going into an Apache NiFi flow (not to a console window). I'd much rather use stdout and not a secondary in-memory buffer as that feels like such a waste of memory. It'd be great if I could remove the last byte of the stdout buffer before flushing.

**EDIT**:
Some folks in the comments are suggesting my use of list comprehensions isn't the way to go here and instead run `json.dumps` on the list. If anyone has an example of how to use this and ensure the last element doesn't have a trailing comma, please show it!

Comment: Why don't you just use `json.dumps` on `list`, rather than construct the output in this somewhat cumbersome manner?

Comment: Output buffering doesn't work like that anyway, and worrying about extra in-memory buffers is premature optimization, especially if you don't thoroughly understand how the normal buffering works.

Comment: (Also, it's rather silly to worry about extra buffering and then throw away the memory for a list to abuse list comprehensions for side effects.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to dump the whole list at once:

```
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(list, separators=(',', ': '))
```

But if you really need to write each element separately you could make the comma conditional:

```
last_index = len(list) - 1
sys.stdout.write("[")
for i, x in enumerate(list):
    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(x, separators=(',', ': '))
    if i < last_index:
        sys.stdout.write(',')
sys.stdout.write("]")
```